# Reading HTML5 Filesystem after directory update

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to make a dynamic interface for interacting with the HTML5 filesystem in Chrome Canary, but I am currently hitting a stumbling block.

I use

```
dirReader.readEntries(function (entries) {
        if (!entries.length){
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0 ; i < entries.length; i++){

            $scope.files.push(entries[i]);
        }

        dirReader.readEntries();

    }, errorHandler);
```

to get them the first time, which works fine. But if I create a new file, and run the code again, it returns nothing.

I imagine it is using an old reference to the file system or something like that, so I imagine I need to reinitialize the file system or the directory reader (That's a guess)? What is the best way to deal with that issue?

Edit: Getting a new reference to the file system does work, but that makes me vomit a little. A better way to do that would still be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excellent HTML5rocks website for [file handling](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/?redirect_from_locale=fr)

> To read the contents of a directory, create a DirectoryReader and call
>   its readEntries() method. There is no guarantee that all of a directory's entries
>   will be returned in a single call to readEntries(). That means you need to keep
>   calling DirectoryReader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.

I read that to mean that a `DirectoryReader` is a one off object. Once you have read it you will get no more data from it. So instead of getting a new file system reference try creating a new `DirectoryReader`.

Comment: I believe I was doing that. In the console I did `fs.root.createReader()` and would use the callback from the readEntries() function to just set a global variable to have the value of entries. That value would have a length of zero, and thus my algorithm would have stopped there anyway.

Comment: Interesting, on closer inspection of your code, you call `readEntries` two different ways, once with `dirEntry`, one without. That seems wrong. Look at the referenced HMTL5rocks site for an example of reading directories. It is close to your code but subtly different.

Comment: That is a bit embarrassing, but that was simply a mistake copying it. It was `$scope.dirReader.readEntries()`, but that detail didn't seem relevant, and I accidentally removed too much when changing it. I apologize for making you think about something that wasn't a real issue.

Comment: It would help if you gave the complete context. Often a problem is not where you first think it is. Also I assume you have checked the console for error messages.

Comment: All calls to dirReader are actually $scope.dirReader, but I just assigned them that later, so it is the same object.

But yeah, the console is clean. When I manually obtained a new dirReader, the same thing would happen. It would return entries, it would just be empty. I think it is just an ugly api.

Comment: I still have a problem with the code you now have, the call on `dirEntries` has no parameter.